# No AppIndicators after upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: indicator, 18.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu 17.10 install to 18.04 yesterday, and I'm noticing that I don't have any AppIndicators anymore. Here's what I tried that didn't work:

- Enable `Ubuntu AppIndicators` in the gnome tweak tools
- Enable `Ubuntu dock` in the gnome tweak tools
- Installed the `KStatusNotifierItem` gnome extension. It fixed the issue for a few minutes, then upon reboot the icons disappeared again and reinstalling it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I experimented a bit with [GNOME shell extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) and it was [Topicons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/) who brought my  indicator for Clementine music player back.